# Powerbuilder-Remove last separator

Tags: powerbuilder, save-as, datawindow, delimited

Hi i'm using PB 12 and I have problems with `SaveasFormattedText`

The funcion works well, but the separator char add one character at the end of each line and I need to delete the last separator.

For example, saveasformattedtext export data like this:

```
data1;data2;data3;data4; 
data1;data2;data3;data4; 
etc.
```

And I need like this:

```
data1;data2;data3;data4 
data1;data2;data3;data4
```

without the ";" at the end.

this my code :

```
dw_report.SaveAsFormattedText("d:/RESULTS2.TXT", EncodingUTF8! , "|", "","~r~n",True)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below function. You might want to add some error checking and more options as you require. the idea is to save each row separately as a line in the file.

```
/*function: f_dw_saveasformattedtext(dw_1, ls_filename, ';')
parameters: adw_dw(datawindow/datastore), as_filename (string), as_separator(string)
*/
long ll_row, ll_rows, ll_colcount, ll_colindex
string ls_colname, ls_coltype, ls_value, ls_lineval
int li_filenum
any la_anyval

ll_rows = adw_dw.rowcount()
ll_colcount = long(adw_dw.Describe("DataWindow.Column.Count"))
li_filenum = FileOpen(as_filename, LineMode!, Write!, LockWrite!, Append!)
if li_filenum  = -1 or isnull(li_filenum) = true then 
    return -1
end if
for ll_row = 1 to ll_rows
    ls_lineval = ''
    for ll_colindex = 1 to ll_colcount
        ls_colname = adw_dw.describe("#" + string(ll_colindex) + ".Name")
        ls_coltype = adw_dw.Describe ( ls_colname + ".ColType" )
        CHOOSE CASE Lower ( Left ( ls_coltype , 5 ) )
                CASE "char(", "char","strin"        //  CHARACTER DATATYPE
                    la_anyval = adw_dw.GetItemString ( ll_row, ls_colname ) 
                CASE "date"                 //  DATE DATATYPE
                    la_anyval = adw_dw.GetItemDate ( ll_row, ls_colname ) 
                CASE "datet"                //  DATETIME DATATYPE
                    la_anyval = adw_dw.GetItemDateTime ( ll_row, ls_colname ) 
                CASE "decim"                //  DECIMAL DATATYPE
                    la_anyval = adw_dw.GetItemDecimal ( ll_row, ls_colname ) 
                CASE "numbe", "long", "ulong", "real", "int"                //  NUMBER DATATYPE 
                    la_anyval = adw_dw.GetItemNumber ( ll_row, ls_colname ) 
                CASE "time", "times"        //  TIME DATATYPE
                    la_anyval = adw_dw.GetItemTime ( ll_row, ls_colname ) 
                CASE ELSE                   
                    SetNull ( la_anyval ) 
        END CHOOSE
        ls_value = string(la_anyval)
        if trim(ls_lineval) = '' then
            ls_lineval = ls_value
        else
            ls_lineval += as_separator + ls_value
        end if
    next //columns
    FileWrite(li_filenum, ls_lineval)
next  //rows

return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to replace a combination of "; that is concatenated
with char(10) char(13) " to only be char(10)char(13). (I might have the
CR/LF ascii codes reversed here).

[Here is this answer](http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C047b98c0-9eda-42b9-be51-3efb8b8905c2@a12g2000yqm.googlegroups.com%3E)

[Here is a possible solution:](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1448033)